# Angular form POST goes to wrong action URL

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

A rails newbie, I have problems submitting a form using Angular JS. while I have specified /contact in the `url` field for `$http` the POST request goes to `root`.

In my rails `routes.rb` I have

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'home/index'
  post 'home/contact' => "home#contact"
  root 'home#index' 
end
```

the Controller is pretty basic

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index

  end

  def contact
    @captcha = params[:g-recpatcha-response]
    @contact = ContactRequest.new(params[...])
    ....
  end
end
```

***Update***

AngularJS is included through `angular-rails` gem, and filed included using `require` attribute in `application.js`

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require jquery.easing.1.3.min
//= require jquery.sticky
//= require jquery.stellar.min
//= require wow.min
//= require custom
//= require contact_me.js
//= require jqBootstrapValidation.js
//= require angular
//= require_tree ./angular
//= require main.js
```

The HTML snippet for `application.html.erb` is as follows

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Etheron</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js', :async => "", :defer => "" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= render "layouts/header" %>
<%= yield %>
<%= render "layouts/footer" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
</body>
</html>
```

and the form is included in `index.html.erb`

```
<div ng-app="etherOn" class="form-contact">
            <div class="required">
                <p>( <span>*</span> fields are required )</p>
            </div>

           <form ng-controller="formController" ng-submit="contactRequest()"  name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="row control-group">
                            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 controls" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : formData.name.$invalid && !formData.name.$pristine }">
                                <label>Name<span>*</span></label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" id="name" required ng-model="formData.name">
                                <!-- <p ng-show="userForm.name.$invalid && !userForm.name.$pristine" class="help-block">You name is required.</p> -->
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="row control-group">
                            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 controls" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : formData.email.$invalid && !formData.email.$pristine }">
                                <label>Email Address<span>*</span></label>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" id="email" required ng-model="formData.email">
                                <!-- <p ng-show="userForm.email.$invalid && !userForm.email.$pristine" class="help-block">You name is required.</p> -->
                            </div>
                        </div> 
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row control-group">
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-12  controls" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : formData.phone.$invalid && !formData.phone.$pristine}" >
                        <label>Phone Number<span>*</span></label>
                        <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number" id="phone" required ng-model="formData.phone">
                        <!-- <p ng-show="userForm.phone.$invalid && !userForm.phone.$pristine" class="help-block">You name is required.</p> -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row control-group">
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 controls" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : formData.message.$invalid && !formData.message.$pristine}" >
                        <label>Message<span>*</span></label>
                        <textarea rows="5" class="form-control" placeholder="Message" id="message" required ng-model="formData.message"></textarea>
                        <!-- <p ng-show="userForm.message.$invalid && !userForm.message.$pristine" class="help-block">You name is required.</p> -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row control-group">
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 controls">
                        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Lf2xAkTAAAAAOpJvpHn10HDPBTGP55ROzl01nIP"> </div>
                        <!-- -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div id="success"></div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-theme-bg btn-lg">Send Message</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>

        </div><!--contact form-->
```

The javascript code is in `main.js` file for form submission

```
var app = angular.module("etherOn", []);

app.controller("formController", function($http, $scope) {
        $scope.formData = {};

        console.log("submit form");

        $scope.contactRequest = function() {
            if($scope.formData.g-recaptcha-response === ""){ //if string is empty
                // TODO: use bootstrap sweet modals here
                alert("Please resolve the captcha and submit!")
            }else{
                var post_data = $.param($scope.formData);
                $http.post({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: 'home/contact',
                    data: post_data,
                    headers : { "X-CSRF-Token" : $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' }
                }).success(function(response){
                    console.log(response);
                    if(response.error === 0){
                        alert("Successfully verified and signed up the user");
                    }else{
                        alert("User verification failed");
                    }
                })
                .error(function(error){

                })
            }               
        }
    });
```

The problem is AngularJS form submission code is never called, tried quite a few snippets from different tutuorials to no help. There are some detaild example but they are all based on ActiveRecord which I do not want to use here, as all I do is generate an email using sendgrid one the form is submitted.

Comment: Where's `contactRequest` defined in your controller? (Hint: it isn't)

Comment: yup changed that to `$scope.contactRequest`, same result :-/

Comment: `ng-submit="contactRequest()"` is, as far as syntax goes, okay, but there is no `contactRequest` function. Maybe that should be: `ng-submit="processForm()"`

Comment: Change `post '/contact' => "home#contact"` to `post 'contact' => "home#contact"`.

Comment: is there a config other than these I might be missing? I changed the configuration to `contact` to no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There wee multiple issues causing this, primarily because of me jumbling up things, I had added an angular-recaptcha module which wasn't loading properly and failed rest of the script executing, removed that, fixed the angular form and then re-enabled captcha to get things working. Thanks y'all for the help!

here's the structure and it works now

`application.js`

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require jquery.easing.1.3.min
//= require jquery.sticky
//= require jquery.stellar.min
//= require wow.min
//= require custom
//= require angular
//= require angular-recaptcha.min.js
//= require main.js
```

`application.html.erb`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Etheron</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=explicit&onload=vcRecaptchaApiLoaded', :async => "", :defer => "", 
    :type =>"text/javascript" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true , :type =>"text/javascript" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body ng-app="etherOn">

<%= render "layouts/header" %>
<%= yield %>
<%= render "layouts/footer" %>
<%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
</body>
</html>
```

form as included in `index.html.erb`

```
<div class="form-contact" ng-controller="formController">
            <div class="required">
                <p>( <span>*</span> fields are required )</p>
            </div>
            <div id="success" class="alert alert-success" ng-show="messages" ng-bind="messages"></div>
            <form name="sentMessage" role="form" novalidate>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="row control-group">
                            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 controls">
                                <label>Name<span>*</span></label>
                                <span class="label label-danger" ng-show="submitted && sentMessage.name.$error.required">Required!</span>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" name="name" required ng-model="contact.name">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="row control-group">
                            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 controls">
                                <label>Email Address<span>*</span></label>
                                <span class="label label-danger" ng-show="submitted && sentMessage.email.$error.required">Required!</span>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" name="email" required ng-model="contact.email">
                            </div>
                        </div> 
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row control-group">
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-12  controls">
                        <label>Phone Number<span>*</span></label>
                        <span class="label label-danger" ng-show="submitted && sentMessage.phone.$error.required">Required!</span>
                        <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number" name="phone" required ng-model="contact.phone">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row control-group">
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 controls">
                        <label>Message<span>*</span></label>
                        <span class="label label-danger" ng-show="submitted && sentMessage.message.$error.required">Required!</span>
                        <textarea rows="5" class="form-control" placeholder="Message" name="message" required ng-model="contact.message"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row control-group">
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 controls">
                        <label>Verify<span>*</span></label>
                        <span class="label label-danger" ng-show="submitted && response === null">Required!</span>
                        <div vc-recaptcha theme="'light'" 
                        key="model.key" 
                        on-create="setWidgetId(widgetId)" 
                        on-success="setResponse(response)"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-theme-bg btn-lg" ng-click="contactRequest(sentMessage)">Send Message</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>

        </div><!--contact form-->
```

and the script

```
angular.module("etherOn", ['vcRecaptcha'])
.config([
    "$httpProvider", function($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['X-CSRF-Token'] = $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content');
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/json; charset=utf-8';
    }
])
.controller("formController",["vcRecaptchaService","$http","$scope", "$timeout", function(vcRecaptchaService,$http, $scope, $timeout) {

        $scope.contact = {};
        $scope.submitted = false;
        $scope.response = null;
        $scope.widgetId = null;
        $scope.model = {
            key: "6Lf2xAkTAAAAAOpJvpHn10HDPBTGP55ROzl01nIP"
        };

        $scope.setResponse = function (response) {
            $scope.response = response;
        };

        $scope.setWidgetId = function (widgetId) {
            $scope.widgetId = widgetId;
        };

        $scope.contactRequest = function(form) {

            // Trigger validation flag.
            $scope.submitted = true;

            // If form is invalid, return and let AngularJS show validation errors.
            if (form.$invalid) {
                return;
            }else{

                var post_data = {  //prepare payload for request
                    'name':$scope.contact.name,
                    'email':$scope.contact.email,
                    'phone':$scope.contact.phone,
                    'message':$scope.contact.message,
                    'captcha':$scope.response  //send g-captcah-reponse to our server
                }

                console.log(post_data);

                $http.post(
                    'home/contact',post_data
                ).success(function(response){
                    console.log(response);
                    if(response.error === 0){
                        $scope.messages = "Thanks!" + $scope.name + "for your request! We will get back to you shortly"
                    }else{
                        $scope.messages = "We are sorry but your request was not processed, please try again."
                    }
                })
                .error(function(error){
                    $scope.messages = "We are sorry but your request was not processed, please try again."
                })
                .finally(function() {
                // Hide status messages after three seconds.
                    $timeout(function() {
                        $scope.messages = null;
                    },  5000);
                    vcRecaptchaService.reload($scope.widgetId);
                });
            }   
        }
    }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you have missed form submit url and $http url.

Form tag submit url is different from url of $http.

First of all, your form tag has no actions. So default action url is "/" (now page)

1. When form is submitted, ng-submit="" is executed.
2. ng-submit block $http executed. ($http is **async block**)
3. After ng-submit block is end, the the form will submit!

so because of the form action url "/", form submit to "/"

And I think you miss more point about 2 above.

Maybe even number 2 process($http post routine) not work

**for miss point**

Rails has checking routine csrf-token. so when your post to a action, the action skipped before_filter :verify_authenticity_token (A) or in angularjs, add csrf-token to $http headers. (B)

```
#(A)
skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token

#(B)
$http({
        method  : 'POST',
        url     : '/contact',
        data    : $.param($scope.formData),  // pass in data as strings
        headers : { "X-CSRF-Token" : $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') }
    })
// $('meta[name="csrf-token"]') tag is generated by layout <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

Comment: I think the problem is that this angular code block never gets called, I added `console.log('submit from angular')` as the first line under this function, it doesn't print in console.

Comment: Also going by documentation of ngSubmit, the form should not have an action attribute, hence I haven't put it there

Comment: See this [ngSubmit](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit). 
By document, you need action if you dont want to submit current page

Comment: `Additionally it prevents the default action (which for form means sending the request to the server and reloading the current page), but only if the form does not contain action, data-action, or x-action attributes.` ; to me it means action should not be present as an attribute .....